# Pass Dynamic variable as prop from slug

Tags: reactjs

In my App.js file I have one reusable element on which I provide a value as props.
Currently the value is somehow manually, I would like React to pass it dinamically, to be taken from it's path i.e `\a`.

```
<Route path="/a" element={<General site="a" />}>    </Route>
<Route path="/b" element={<General site="b" />}>    </Route>
```

Instead of providing a static prop as `a` or `b` I want it to be taken from it's path var ==> `/a` to `a` and `/b` to `b`

So I was hoping of using something like this:

```
<Route path="/b" element={<General site={Route.path} />}>  </Route>
```

Where `{path}` has to have the value without `/`.

Hope that it is clear what I am trying to achieve.

Later Edit. I tried with `{Route.path}`, but if you have 2 or more variables, react will pick the last one which is not ok. Seems like a bug. Whenever you click on `/a` it provides the path as `\b` which is not correct

```
<Route path="/a" element={<General site={Route.path} />}>    </Route>
<Route path="/b" element={<General site={Route.path} />}>    </Route>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic path (I assume you are using `react-router` library):

```
<Route path='/:site' render={(props => <General site={props.match.params.site} />)} />
```

Comment: Thanks Marek! The thing is that I use variable `a` as a query for my database, so I need to pass the value from the path `/a` as a props to the General object. If I use `path='/:site'` how React will now to provide value a or b?

Comment: I've used what you suggested. We are close but the `props.match.params.site` returns `\a` and I want only the value `a` without ==> \

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Route V6, use the hooks `useLocation` and `useParams`.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams

Suppose you were making an editor page and wanted to show same page for creating a new doc or editing an existing doc.

If paths are `/new-doc` or `/docs/:docId`

```js
import {
  useLocation,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

...

export default function MyPage(props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  const docId = location.pathname !== "/new-doc" && params.docId; //path param docId can be fetched as `params.docId`
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I simply need the value from path. I need to extract the value from that given path `/a` to `a`

Comment: Did this help? Or do you mean that you are only looking for `path.substr(1)` in your example ?

Comment: I tried with site={Route.path} but if you have 2 or more elements `\a` and `\b` , then it will insert all the time the last one ==>b for both of them, so there seems to be a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question now. Can you add examples of what and in which component you are trying to achieve this? I previously thought that you wanted the path value in your` <General .../>` component. So you could use the `useLocation` hook in General component to get the path, or you could have a dynamic path and use `useParams` hook to get the path param. But now I'm not sure what exactly are you looking for. Are you getting `"\a"` instead of `"a"`?

Comment: yes! I need the value of the path I got `\a` instead of `a`